# How to hike from Kiangan to Hungduan, near Banaue, in the Philippines?

Tags: hiking, philippines

I have heard rumors of a roughly six-hour hike from the town of Kiangan to Hungduan in the Ifugao province of the Philippines, passing near several rice terraces.  It supposedly passes through the village of Maggok.

My questions are:

- What should I expect if I go (is it well-marked)?
- What is the transportation situation like at the end of the trail from Hungduan to Bananue?

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hiking and should go to http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isn't that just a method of travelling ie by foot?

Comment: Given that he's asking about travel logistics I think it is on the right stack exchange..

Answer (score 3):

I found a mention of Kiangan here: http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=WInyBgZA45sC&pg=PT203&lpg=PT203#v=onepage&q&f=false

You might want to liaise directly with those from Kiangan, [here](http://kiangan.gov.ph/?page_id=1118) are some tour guides and their mobile numbers.